# Setup web folder for multiple developers and Apache

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, configuration, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to setup a web folder on LAMP with Ubuntu 14.04 where :

1. Apache/PHP can read everything inside. (**r-x** for folders and **r--** for files)
2. Multiple users in a "devs" group can do anything inside. (**rwx** for folders and **rw-** for files)
3. Newly created folders and files have the same properties as above.

I know there is [this](https://serverfault.com/a/126405) answer that looked pretty good at first, until i tried to access from the web and i got a 403 permission denied.

---

Should i use only one "dev" user that can modify the web folder ?

I could also use ACL ?

**EDIT :** Not a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/a/357109/354883 because it doesn't solve the problem for newly created files.

**MY SOLUTION:** Since i didn't found anything on the standard permission system that could do exactly what i wanted, i checked ACL.

What i did:

- `sudo apt-get install acl`  You also may wanna mount your parition so it enables ACL
- `sudo setfacl -Rm g:coders:rwx,g:www-data:r-x,o:--- webfolder`
- `sudo setfacl -Rm d:g:coders:rwx,d:g:www-data:r-x,d:o:--- webfolder`

Comment: @Iain I explained why it isn't.

Comment: The section headed "Default new file permissions" seems to cover newly created files.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache and users of the group "dev" have permission to do anything you should:

Includes users who belong to the group "dev" www-data group, and add the www-data user in the group "dev"

Change the umask default Apache and users of the group "dev"

1. Add or edit /etc/apache2/envvars

   `umask 002`

   `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
2. Add or edit ~/.bashrc you users (**or enhance it**)

   `umask 002`

   `chmod 775 -R webfolder`

**Note**: Note that this way all users who belong to "dev" will have privileges to modify files created by all users "dev". It can be dangerous for your
structure

Comment: Doesn't this make the apache and php able to write on all files ?